# Why isn't Angular syncing fields with the same formControlName?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two mat-select fields bound to the same `formControlName` within the same form using reactive forms. I would have thought that making a change in one would be reflected in the other, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Why is that? Does it have something to do with change detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to make 2 different formControl and you need subscribe the valueChanges.
For example:

```
this.firstControl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.secondControl.setValue(x, {emitEvent: false}));

this.secondControl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.firstControl.setValue(x, {emitEvent: false}));
```

{ emitEvent: false } need, if you make it vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easer way is **not to have** two inputs with the same formControlName. Use one input with formControlName and the another using ngModel

```
<input formControlName="control">
<input [ngModel]="myForm.get('control').value"
       (ngModelChange)="myForm.get('control').setValue($event)"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```